# Extracting Data from an Area file

Tags: jython, visad

I am trying to extract information at a specific location (lat,lon) from different satellite images. These images are were given to me in the AREA format and I cooked up a simple jython script to extract temperature values like so.

While the script works, here is small snippet from it that prints out the data value at a point.

```
 from edu.wisc.ssec.mcidas import AreaFile as af
 url="adde://localhost/imagedata?&PORT=8113&COMPRESS=gzip&USER=idv&PROJ=0&  VERSION=1&DEBUG=false&TRACE=0&GROUP=FL&DESCRIPTOR=8712C574&BAND=2&LATLON=29.7276 -85.0274 E&PLACE=ULEFT&SIZE=1 1&UNIT=TEMP&MAG=1 1&SPAC=4&NAV=X&AUX=YES&DOC=X&DAY=2012002 2012002&TIME=&POS=0&TRACK=0"
 a=af(url);
 value=a.getData();
 print value

array([[I, [array([I, [array('i', [2826, 2833, 2841, 2853])])])
```

So what does this mean?

Please excuse me if the question seems trivial,  while I am comfortable with python I am really new to dealing with scientific data.

#### Note

Here is a link to the entire [script](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/7519434).

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, I found out that the Area objects returns data in multiples of four. So the very first value is what I am looking for.

Grabbing the value is as simple as :

```
   ar[0][0][0]
```